# Can't able fetch data form json using class in flutter(dart)

Tags: json, flutter, api, rest, dart

I am trying to retrieve the temperature data from a weather API using a generated class in Dart, created with the JSON to Dart Extension. I have been able to retrieve the entire JSON response from the API, but when I try to access a single data using the class, it just prints null.

```
Future<Current> getweatherData({required String location}) async {
  final _response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=a80c4dfea39ef2093f3a0423200bed6a&query=$location'));
  print(_response.body); // Add this line to print the response from the API
  final _bodyJson = jsonDecode(_response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final _data = Current.fromJson(_bodyJson);
  print(_data.temperature); //showing null --
  return _data;
}
```

Generated code.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'current.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Current {
  @JsonKey(name: 'observation_time')
  String? observationTime;
  int? temperature;
  @JsonKey(name: 'weather_code')
  int? weatherCode;
  @JsonKey(name: 'weather_icons')
  List<String>? weatherIcons;
  @JsonKey(name: 'weather_descriptions')
  List<String>? weatherDescriptions;
  @JsonKey(name: 'wind_speed')
  int? windSpeed;
  @JsonKey(name: 'wind_degree')
  int? windDegree;
  @JsonKey(name: 'wind_dir')
  String? windDir;
  int? pressure;
  int? precip;
  int? humidity;
  int? cloudcover;
  int? feelslike;
  @JsonKey(name: 'uv_index')
  int? uvIndex;
  int? visibility;
  @JsonKey(name: 'is_day')
  String? isDay;

  Current({
    this.observationTime,
    this.temperature,
    this.weatherCode,
    this.weatherIcons,
    this.weatherDescriptions,
    this.windSpeed,
    this.windDegree,
    this.windDir,
    this.pressure,
    this.precip,
    this.humidity,
    this.cloudcover,
    this.feelslike,
    this.uvIndex,
    this.visibility,
    this.isDay,
  });

  factory Current.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$CurrentFromJson(json);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CurrentToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  getLaundriesApi() async {
    try {
      var token = LoginRes.fromJson(GetStorage("storage").read("user")).token;
      var response =
          await httpClient.get(Uri.parse("${baseUrl}getLaundries"), headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer ${token!}",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var res = LaundriesRes.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        return res;
      } else {
        log("error getLaundriesApi");
        throw Exception("Failed");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      log(err.toString());
    }
    return LoginRes.fromJson(
        json.decode("{\"success\": false, \"message\": \"Error !!!\"}"));
  }
```

2. 

```
class LaundriesRes {
  bool? success;
  String? message;
  List<Laundries>? laundries;

  LaundriesRes({this.success, this.message, this.laundries});

  LaundriesRes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    message = json['message'];
    if (json['laundries'] != null) {
      laundries = <Laundries>[];
      json['laundries'].forEach((v) {
        laundries!.add(Laundries.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['success'] = success;
    data['message'] = message;
    if (laundries != null) {
      data['laundries'] = laundries!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Laundries {
  int? id;
  String? logo;
  String? type;
  String? name;
  String? detail;
  int? isActive;
  String? accountNumber;
  int? bankId;
  String? register;
  String? openHour;
  String? closeHour;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? isFeatured;

  Laundries(
      {this.id,
        this.logo,
        this.type,
        this.name,
        this.detail,
        this.isActive,
        this.accountNumber,
        this.bankId,
        this.register,
        this.openHour,
        this.closeHour,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.isFeatured});

  Laundries.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    logo = json['logo'];
    type = json['type'];
    name = json['name'];
    detail = json['detail'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];
    accountNumber = json['account_number'];
    bankId = json['bank_id'];
    register = json['register'];
    openHour = json['open_hour'];
    closeHour = json['close_hour'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    isFeatured = json['is_featured'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['logo'] = logo;
    data['type'] = type;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['detail'] = detail;
    data['is_active'] = isActive;
    data['account_number'] = accountNumber;
    data['bank_id'] = bankId;
    data['register'] = register;
    data['open_hour'] = openHour;
    data['close_hour'] = closeHour;
    data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    data['is_featured'] = isFeatured;
    return data;
  }
}
```

3.GetX Controller class

```
getLaundries(BuildContext? context) async {
    loading.value = true;
    update();
    laundriesRes = await repository.getServices();
    if (laundriesRes != null) {
      if (laundriesRes!.success == true) {
          serviceList = laundriesRes!.services!.laundry!;
        loading.value = false;
        update();
      } else {
        loading.value = false;
        update();
        HBDialog.failure(text: "${laundriesRes!.message}");
      }
    } else {
      loading.value = false;
      HBDialog.failure(text: "Error.");
    }
  }
```